# Custom display layout

Tags: macos, windows-10, synergy

I have a iMac with 3 displays (2 external plus the built in) What i am trying to do it create a sideways C like effect with my monitors:

[iMac display][iMac][iMac Display]
   [Macbook]              [Windows]

Is this possible? The iMac is the server and synergy sees the 2 displays attached it as one big display? How do I get it so that I can go to the bottom of those displays control the 2 extra computers?

Answer (score 0):

The synergy config file allows you to wrap any edge to any device using percentage ranges to control when screen size differences may occur. Within the [config file](https://github.com/symless/synergy/wiki/Text-Config) modify the "links" section to read something like this:

```
section: links
    your-imac:
        down(0,50) = your-macbook
        down(50,100) = your-winpc
    your-macbook:
        up = your-imac(0,50)
        right = your-winpc
    your-winpc:
        left = your-macbook
        up = your-imac(50,100)
end
```

If you prefer to leave a hole in the middle you can adjust the numbers based on your actual screen size. This will put the cursor closer to the correct position on the edge of your external displays:

```
section: links
    your-imac:
        down(0,30) = your-macbook
        down(70,100) = your-winpc
    your-macbook:
        up = your-imac(0,30)
        right = your-winpc
    your-winpc:
        left = your-macbook
        up = your-imac(70,100)
end
```